# Laravel: How to save an array of objects sent from the frontend?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, axios

I have an endpoint I am calling to save an array of objects:

**Frontend**

```
saveLinks: function() {
    let links = [{"title": "Welcome", "url": "http://www.ccc.com"}, {"title": "Bye", "url": "http://www.ddd.com"}];
    
    axios.post('/admin/endpoint', {
        link_data: links
    });

}
```

**Laravel**

```
public function saveLinks(Request $request) 
{
    $links = $request->link_data;

    $user = User::where('id', '=', 1)->first();
    
    $user->links = $links;
    $user->save();
 
}
```

my `links` field is empty though.  Am I sending the data over incorrectly for an array an objects?

Comment: did you typo on ```axios.post('/admin/endpoint', { link_data: links }``` because in your post you're missing a closing paren

Comment: just a typo copying it over, fixing now thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted, something must be up somewhere else. Can you show the routes? Or maybe add a bit more info on where you're noticing things going wrong when you say your 'links field is empty though'?